# Tortoise and Hare don't have adresses, C++

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Element
{
public:
    Element* next;
    double field;
};

class LinkedList
{
protected:
    Element* begin;
    int num;
public:
    int Number() {return num;}
    LinkedList() 
    {
        begin = NULL;
        num = 0;
    }
    LinkedList(LinkedList& L) 
    {
        begin = new Element;
        num = L.Number();
        begin = L.begin;
    }

    virtual void push(double a)
    {
        Element* cur = begin;
        if(begin==NULL)
        {
            num = 1;
            begin = new Element;
            begin->field = a;
            begin->next = NULL;
            return;
        }

        while(cur->next!=NULL)
        {
            cur = cur->next;
        }
        num ++ ;

        cur->next = new Element;
        cur->next->field = a;
        cur->next->next = NULL;
    }
    virtual double pop()
    {
        Element* cur = begin;
        Element* prev = NULL;

        if(begin==NULL)
        {
            return -1;
        }
        if(num==1)
        {
            double res = begin->field;
            num--;
            return res;
        }

        while(cur->next!=NULL)
        {
            prev = cur;
            cur = cur->next;
        }
        double res = cur->field;
        prev->next = NULL;
        delete cur;
        num--;
        return res;
    }

    ~LinkedList()
    {
        num = 0;
        Element* cur = begin;
        if(cur!=NULL)
            cur = cur->next;
        while(cur!=NULL)
        {
            Element* prev = cur;
            cur = cur->next;
            delete prev;
        }
        if(begin!=NULL)
            delete begin;
    }
    Element* operator[](int i)
    {
        if(i<0 || i>num) return NULL;
        int k = 0;
        Element* cur = begin;
        for(k=0;k<i;k++)
        {
            cur = cur->next;
        }
        return cur;
    }
};

class R_LinkedList: public LinkedList{
public:

    double pop() {
        double res = begin->field;
        begin = begin->next;
        num--;
        return res;
    }
    bool cycle_search() {
        Element* tortoise = begin, *hare = begin;

        while(tortoise && hare && hare->next) {
            tortoise = tortoise->next;
            hare = hare->next->next;
            if(tortoise == hare) {
                cout << "Got loop" << endl;
                return 1;
            }           
        }
        cout << "No loop" << endl; return 0;
    }
};

int main()
{
    R_LinkedList l;
    l.push(2); l.push(3); l.push(6);l.push(3);l.push(6);
    cout  << l[2]->field << endl;
    l[4]->next = l[1];
    l.cycle_search();
    return 0;
}
```

Scroll down, then up.

So I have this code and trying to implement classic "tortoise and hare" cycle finding algorythm (and also overload virtual function, but that's not the problem [yet]). And it works fine! It prints value, it says happily "Got loop!"
And then it breaks, screaming

```
HEAP[TestConsole2.exe]: Invalid address specified to RtlValidateHeap( 002E0000, 002EF8F0 )
```

An adress problem. Favorite. Honestly tried to debug, and he worked it all throught the end and broke again. So it's something with the destructor, but - hell - have no idea what exactly.
Or maybe it's about the algorythm itself. Or I am the problem 'cause don't see something obvious or lack fundamentals.

Comment: Try to shorten the code so that the problem still occurs. No one will read through 200 lines of code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an issue in `LinkedList` destructor.
When you assign the `next` element of `l[4]` to be `l[1]`, basically you have cycle (which seems what you wanted).
But the last element (`l[4]`) points on an existing element.
So in the destructor you are trying to destroy `l[1]` twice : the first time just after delete `l[0]`, and the second time after deleting `l[4]`.
You should review the design of your list, and in particular the way you destroy it.

Comment: Might be worth recommending he use his already made `pop` member function for the destructor (would make the code maybe 3-5 lines max and far more readable).